# Ask politely if there is any fee for a training

Tags: politeness

I am attending a training, but they did not mention if it is free or not.
How to ask politely if there is any fee for this training?

Comment: *How much does it cost?*

Comment: If you mean to say that you are already receiving the training, the question might not be how to ask *politely* if there is a fee, but how to ask *apologetically* if there is a fee.

Comment: Ask your fellow trainees first.

Comment: I'm sorry, no one told me if there was a fee for this training. Could you fill me in on the charges?

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanted to be polite, you could assume there is a fee even if you did not know for sure. If it's free you'll be told that there is no cost.

Hello Mr. SoAndSo, I was wondering what the cost might be for [this event]